# Android Base64 Decoding Encoding incorrect when added to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, encoding, base64

I'm encoding an image to Base64 so i can put it into a JSONObject and upload it to a web server.

This issue I'm having is that it appears when the encoded string is put in the JSONObject it changes it to something invalid. I have been using an [Online Base64 Decoder](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) to check the results.

```
public static Triple<Boolean, String, JSONObject> validateAppC(Context context, String userId, String mParam1, String pack_status_id){

//**This is a larger method so I've only included code that creates the JSONObject directly**//

JSONObject getFields = new JSONObject();
    try{
        getFields.put("work_from_date", appCArray[0]);
        getFields.put("work_from_time", appCArray[1]);
        getFields.put("work_to_date", appCArray[2]);
        getFields.put("work_to_time", appCArray[3]);
        getFields.put("question_1", appCArray[4]);
        getFields.put("question_2", appCArray[5]);
        getFields.put("question_3", appCArray[6]);
        getFields.put("question_4", appCArray[7]);
        getFields.put("question_5", appCArray[8]);
        getFields.put("question_6", appCArray[9]);
        getFields.put("question_7", appCArray[10]);
        getFields.put("question_8", appCArray[11]);
        getFields.put("question_9", appCArray[12]);
        getFields.put("question_10", appCArray[13]);
        getFields.put("question_11", appCArray[14]);
        getFields.put("question_12", appCArray[15]);
        getFields.put("question_13", appCArray[16]);
        getFields.put("question_14", appCArray[17]);
        getFields.put("question_15", appCArray[18]);
        getFields.put("coss_accept_reject", appCArray[19]);
        getFields.put("coss_same_shift", appCArray[20]);
        getFields.put("coss_same_shift_reason", appCArray[21]);
        getFields.put("coss_rejected_reason", appCArray[22]);
        getFields.put("coss_recipient_name", appCArray[23]);
        getFields.put("coss_location", appCArray[24]);
        getFields.put("manager_name", appCArray[25]);
        getFields.put("manager_signature", appCArray[26]);

        String dir = context.getString(R.string.directoryUrl) + context.getPackageName() + "/";
        String filename = "user_" + userId + "_sig.png";

        if(pack_status_id.equals("4") || pack_status_id.equals("6")) {
            dir = context.getString(R.string.directoryUrl) + context.getPackageName() + "/files/" + pack_id + "/appendix_c/";
            filename = "appendix_c_coss_sig.png";
        }

        File directory = new File(dir);
        File mypath= new File(directory,filename);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mypath.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        //Here the encoded string is valid and produces my image perfectly.

        final int chunkSize = 2048;
        for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i += chunkSize) {
            Log.d("encoded", encoded.substring(i, Math.min(encoded.length(), i + chunkSize)));
        }

        JSONObject cossSignatureData = new JSONObject();

        cossSignatureData.put("image_type", "image/png");
        cossSignatureData.put("image_data", encoded);

        getFields.put("coss_signature_data", cossSignatureData);

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return new Triple<>(isValid, str, getFields);
}
```

I call this method using the following code:

```
Triple validationResults = PackViewActivity.validateAppC(getApplicationContext(), userId, pack_id, pack_status_id);

        JSONObject getFields = (JSONObject)validationResults.third;

        data = "data=" + getFields;

        //Here the encoded string is NOT valid and produces nothing.

        final int chunkSize = 2048;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += chunkSize) {
            Log.d("json upload appC", data.substring(i, Math.min(data.length(), i + chunkSize)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As the OP mentioned in the comments, the issue was that there were backslashes in the JSON string. The issue was resolved by performing a replaceAll to get rid of the backslashes.

---

**Original Answer**

If you are comparing the output of your loop inside `validateAppC()`  against the output of the loop after you return your data, then that might be your problem... I'm assuming you're using your log outputs to copy/paste into the online decoder, so this makes sense to me.

1. In the first loop, you're dumping substrings of the encoded image
2. In the second loop you're outputting substrings of your `getFields` object's `toString()` method

Try changing the second for loop (the one in your second code snippet) to this:

```
String encoded = getFields.getString("image_data");
for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i += chunkSize) {
    Log.d("encoded", encoded.substring(i, Math.min(encoded.length(), i + chunkSize)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @thomaspsk When i print out the log as you suggested I get the same valid base64 string. But when it's put into the JSONObject it becomes invalid.

Comment: Having looked back at this I figured out that the JSON string contained backslashes. removing these with replaceAll did the trick. As your answer lead to my solution I'll give you the green tick if you update you answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Done. I'm glad you got to the bottom of this